# create textbox dynamically and get it's value

Tags: asp.net

```
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
t1.Text="123";
qwe2.controls.AddControl(t1);
```

I added textbox dynamically to qwe2 
qwe2 is just a panel

```
<asp:panel ID="qwe2" runat="server"></asp:panel>
```

and then on button_submit  a have a function

```
public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ var x = t1.Text; }
```

but `t1.text` is empty why so? and how to get the value;

Comment: Is it throwing an error or is it just an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add your textbox on all postback when you add control dynamically

```
    public void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       

        if(!ispostback)
        {
        }

        TextBox t1 = new TextBox();t1.Text="123";
        t1.ID ="txtDynamic";
        qwe2.controls.AddControl(t1);
    }

    public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
         TextBox t1 = (TextBox)qwe2.FindControl("txtDynamic");
         var x = t1.Text    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember when ever you create dynamic controls, on post back of page those controls will be removed from page. In order to access those dynamic controls use client side scripting like javascript, jquery.

In your example, get button click on clientside.

```
//server side
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
t1.Text="123";
t1.ID ="txtDynamic";
qwe2.controls.AddControl(t1);

//client side
<asp:button id="button" runat="server" text="click" onClientClick="return callme();" />

<script>
function callme()
{
   var textvalue = document.getElementByID('#txtDynamic').value;
}
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

create button and give id to it

```
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();t1.Text="123";
t1.ID ="txtDynamic";
qwe2.controls.AddControl(t1);
```

on button click

```
 public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
     TextBox t1 = (TextBox)qwe2.FindControl("txtDynamic");
      var x = t1.Text
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add an ID to the textbox then do `textBoxId.Text;`